# Running IntelliJ debugger with maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: java, debugging, maven, intellij-idea

I have a libGDX project that is built using maven. I use the maven-antrun-plugin to run the project immediately after it's built, to make it so I can test new builds quickly from the IDE. A problem I've encountered though is that I have no idea how to use IntelliJ's debugger with the java program run by the maven-antrun-plugin.

Here's the code for the plugin in my pom.xml:

```
<!-- this runs the game when you invoke: mvn integration-test -Pdesktop -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <java fork="true" classname="${mainClass}" classpathref="maven.test.classpath">
                        <sysproperty key="java.library.path" value="target/natives"/>
                        <jvmarg value="-ea"/>
                    </java>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And to clarify, what I need to do is attach the IntelliJ debugger to the java program run by this plugin.

Comment: You can do this by adding these JVM options: `-agentlib:jdwp=server=y,suspend=n,transport=dt_socket,port=xxxx` where `xxxx` is a port number >= 1024. Then launch a remote debug session on localhost, port xxxx.

Comment: Works almost perfectly, thanks! Only change I had to make was change port=xxxx to address=xxxx.

Comment: You could just set the fork to false, and run the maven goal as debug, no?

Comment: The project won't run without fork set to true. Honestly, I don't really understand why, as I started off the project from a maven archetype and fork has always been set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answering my own question so it doesn't remain unaccepted. Answer was gotten from the comment by fge.

I had to launch a remote debugging session using the following JVM args:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=xxxx
```

Where xxxx is a port number greater than or equal to 1024.